# Do I need to call sync on file descriptor after using Files move operation?

Tags: java, io, nio

I want to move two files to a different directory in same filesystem. 
Concrete example, I want to move `/var/bigFile` to `/var/path/bigFile`, and `/var/smallFile` to `/var/path/smallFile`.

Currently I use `Files.move(source, target)`, without any options, moving the small file first and big file second. I need this order since there is another process waiting for this files to arrive, and the order is important.

Problem is that, sometimes I see the creation date for small file being greater than the creation date for the big file, like the moving order is not followed.

Initially I thought I have to do a sync, but it does not make sense.

Given the fact that the move will actually be a simple rename, there is no system buffers included, to force them to be flushed to disk.

Timestamp for the files was checked using `ls -alrt` command.

Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: What happens if you include [`ATOMIC_MOVE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/StandardCopyOption.html#ATOMIC_MOVE) as an option?

Comment: If you move across file systems, a move becomes a copy. And, the time stamp you normally see in ls is the update time stamp. How are you checking the time stamp?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24441/get-file-created-creation-time

Comment: Sync *what* file descriptor? `Files.move()` doesn't provide any file descriptors.

Comment: Erwin, that was the issue. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Marquis, I was trying to do a hack to open a file output stream on the file which was moved, and just do a dummy getFD().sync(). Thus I think this is a viable hack, as long as you move files between filesystems (where in fact we have a copy, and system buffers are used).